# iPhone Debugging : Process launch failed : timed out trying to launch app

Tags: ios, debugging

I don't know what he is going on with my IPhone. I cannot debug with. I already check the **profile provisioning** in **Code signing** and that's not the problem. It seems that with another IPhone everything work perfectly.

*any answer will be appreciated :)*

***That a dump of my IPhone when i try to launch it.***

link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC0rW.jpg
[image]

***or***

[image]

Comment: Try to exit the app you are trying to debug in iPhone(double tap home button on iPhone and not via Xcode debugger) or to reboot iPhone. I get this when there is an instance of the app is running already from previous debug session.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe you for some reason have to many apps running in background on you iPhone. Try to close all the apps and then reboot your device.

Comment: @user1264176 "Try to exit the app you are trying to debug " You were right, but the problem still with another error. I update my post. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, still looks to me like some internal problem with either Xcode or iOS. Did you try to relaunch Xcode and reboot the device? I am not sure if it is related but **backboardd[28] <Error>: HID:** may be related to some accessories you have connected to iPhone or some problem with maybe USB drivers on host machine. Maybe try to reboot your mac. This is pretty wild guess.

Comment: @user1264176 "Try to close all the apps and then reboot your device" still get the problem.

Comment: @user1264176 I just boot my mac and launch xcode then when i compiled the error show. With another IPhone it's work but not that one. This is very strange

Comment: Could you please make another screenshot of what you get in logs? With some context, just like you did earlier. Alternatively you could try to reset your device to factory settings, this is a bit painful if you have lots of profiles and apps installed there and **you will probably have to activate it again so be prepared**. I am not an expert in kernel internals but it seems to me something went wrong there basing on messages like **checking a pid number -1**.

Comment: I am out of ideas. Try to google **#define EIO 5 // Input/output error** in context of debug server maybe that is what you see as **err = 0x00000005** in your output. I would try to reset settings of iPhone one by one up until the full device reset if it is an option for you (meaning you can easily restore all apps and active iPhone after reset)